# Assertions and failures appears with 0

Tags: assertions, web-api-testing, frisby.js

I'm exploring the Frisby tool

I am trying out a simple test (below) and when the test fails the failures count is 0

```js
var frisby = require('frisby');

describe ('Endpoints page', function (){
    it('1- Endpoint main board', function() {
        return frisby.get('https://SDF.DSF')
            .expect('status', 200);
         
    });
    it('2- verify random endpoints working properly', function() {
        return frisby.get('https://DF.DSF')
            .expect('status', 100);
    });
});
```

[image: Screen Grab]

Comment: Can you try giving the expected values within quotes ? expect('status', '200');

Comment: thats whats happened

Finished in 0.023 seconds
2 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped


(node:10724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: HTTP status 200 !== 200
    at FrisbySpec.status (C:\Users\amrka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\frisby\src\frisby\expects.js:25:12)
    at response (C:\Users\amrka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\frisby\src\frisby\spec.js:373:23)
    at _fetch._fetch.then.response (C:\Users\amrka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\frisby\src\frisby\spec.js:214:34)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by executing the code using jest not jasmine command